# Can a php script hang and fail to set a cookie if the processing to generate the cookie takes too long?

Tags: php

```
public function setGeoCookie()
{

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
  
  if (wp_is_mobile()) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!isset( $_COOKIE['location'])) {
    if (false === ($cached = get_transient($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))) {
      $geo = $this->geoAPI->getResult();
      $closest_city = $this->sql_get_closest($geo['latitude'], $geo['longitude']);
      $closest_location = $closest_city->slug;
      set_transient($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $location, 3600*24*2 );
      setcookie("location", $closest_location, time() + (3600*24*2));
    } else {
      setcookie("location", $cached, time() + (3600*24*2));
    }
  }
}
}
```

So this code worked on staging, it didn't work on production during peak hours, and now it works again on production, I am wondering if a php script may get interrupted when the computer takes too long to process the script. This script is supposed to run on every GET request, so because the GET request can take some time, I am actually surprised that the cookie doesn't get generated no matter how many GET calls you make. Is there a way to debug this on production servers, because I can't reproduce the error on staging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. PHP scripts have runtime limit, set by max_execution_time in php.ini. Other timeouts may apply on top depending on your server stack and settings.

To collect information, write log entries along with timestamps into a log file.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to increase the runtime limit for this script in particular and not other scripts?

Comment: That depends on your server configuration. But you can try https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php